# How to make an ASP.Net page with a C# code behind that will work in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I need to develop a page for Sharepoint.

Basically it is a 3 step process that takes some inputs, gets some data and shows a preview of it, then allows the data to be sent off attached to an email.

I know ASP.Net and C#.Net, and the problem should be reasonably easy to solve with an ASP.Net page and a C# code behind.

However I've never had to work with Sharepoint before, and I don't know what is required to make the page 'work in Sharepoint'.

**Is there anything special that needs to be done to make it work in Sharepoint?** Is an ASPX page the right approach for this sort of problem?

(I'm developing on an XP machine using Visual Studio 2008.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an ASPX page with code-behind by putting the ASPX page in the 12 _layout directory and GACing the DLL.  It's not very fun :)

Edit: A tutorial... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SharePoint2.aspx

Edit again: Noticed you said Windows XP.  SharePoint 2007 will only work on Server 2003.

Comment: What, you don't like re-GACing, iisreset and wait for SP to warm up every time you need to test a tweak? :)

Comment: I would rather slam my hand in a car door, repeatedly, then touch that project again.

Comment: Thanks for that :) From the comments it sounds like something I should try to avoid if I can! Also, I'm just developing in XP, while I get a Server 2003 VM sorted out, its the first time anyone at my work has really touched sharepoint unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

The answer here:

[ASP.net page without a codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563585/asp-net-page-without-a-codebehind)

has your answer for here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very loaded question with a very long answer. Any short answer will probably just create more questions. You need to get a [book like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470117567) and read it cover to cover.

Comment: I figured as much, Sharepoint doesn't seem to be a technology you can just pick up and learn as you go too easily - I might suggest this book to my boss :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article a couple of days ago that, amongst other things, covers how to make a [custom application page in SharePoint](http://furuknap.blogspot.com/2009/02/find-number-of-users-currently-logged.html) using a code-behind C# file. Scroll down to Administration page in the article if you just need to get the page up and running.

Also, the first issue of [Understanding SharePoint Journal](http://www.understandingsharepoint.com/journal/volume-1/issue-1) covers a more elaborate example that is used in the CodePlex [SPCurrentUsers](http://www.codeplex.com/SPCurrentUsers) project.

.b